# How to set the popupwindow background with anchor

Tags: android, popupwindow

I am trying to create a `PopupWindow` with a anchor(an arrow)  like this:

[image]

And I have an image for background `popup_bg` like this:

[image]

Now I tried to set the background for the layout of the popupwindow:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/popup_bg">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/popText"
        android:text="@string/map_choose_point"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But I got this:

[image]

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below example

1) **[SuperTooltips](https://github.com/nhaarman/supertooltips)**

2) **[ShowcaseView](https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView)**

From that first link example look like below image

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. But I wonder if the tooltip can update its position according to user's click?